# Porting RTOS in STM32F4 board

Tags: embedded, stm32f4

I want to port a RTOS in STM32F4Disco board. I'm a newbie in this area and unable to understand how to adjust the configurations according to a new target and the whole porting process. So right now, I need to understand from where should I start and resources I've to go through to accomplish this. I've searched for documentation and guides which will enrich basic level knowledge in this purpose but couldn't understand which one to follow, what will be the first step to dive into it, what will be the flow of tasks I should follow. Also if I need to learn any script or language, please let me know.

Is there anyone who could provide me any direction regarding this?

Edit: I've got [this guide](https://github.com/RIOT-OS/RIOT/wiki/Porting-Guide) but I need something detail. I'm not trying to write any RTOS, I just want to port Tizen RT in a new target i.e. STM32F4Disco board.

Comment: It might be a bit ambitious if you are a newbie in this area. RTOS are deeply customized to the target, and porting one RTOS to a different platform is a very complicated task. You will have to have some good C / ASM programming skills. You could start by analysing the existing RTOS for STM32 such as [ChibiOS](http://www.chibios.org/)

Comment: The core is already supported, you _"only have to port the peripherals"_. Which depending on the features required, needs deep knowledge of the entire chip, and the RTOS. You might be better off getting your feet wet first by using an RTOS that is ready for an F4, ChibiOS for example.

Comment: ["so that it can fit into (...) devices which typically equip with (...) less than 2MB RAM, and less than 16MB Flash."](https://wiki.tizen.org/Tizen_RT). Most likely out of range for an STM32F4 (max. 384KB of internal RAM and 2MB of Flash). Find another OS targeted at the intended device range. You'll not have all the features of the full-featured Linux-like Tizen of course, but you probably won't need them. It may be easier to port an existing application to another OS than porting the whole OS.

Comment: Why ? @jimmyB  less than 2MB RAM, and less than 16MB Flash that means no problem i think.

Comment: Seriously? - Because "less than 16MB" is just not the same as "less than 2MB".

Comment: check and check again.... Tizen RT requirements are RAM less than 2MB and flash less than 16MB.....And the STM32F4  ( max. 384KB ram and flash 2MB according to you) ... 
So whats the problem ?

Comment: Why are all those requirements stated as less than? It is just a way of confusing people.

Comment: Why would anyone post less than requirements for memory? Thats ridiculous.

Comment: To make people understand how tiny it is, hope it makes sense!

Comment: What RTOS are you trying to port? I believe STM32F4 already supports FreeRTOS and mbed-rtos (good for starters), so why not use something that already runs on that architecture?